# Getting more than one Legend object in LegendCollection to stack vertically when chart renders

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, charts, mschart

I'm trying to learn the mschart control. I want to create a histogram chart that has a stat panel to the right that displays statistics about the chart. I tried doing this by creating a Legend object docked to the right. [image: Example graph]

I would like the boxes to stack vertically to the right of the chart.  Currently each box represents a Legend object in the LegendsCollection.

Code:

```
 private void CreateStatPanel( Chart chart ) {
         var legend = new Legend
            {
               Title = "Basic Stats",
               TitleAlignment = StringAlignment.Near,
               TitleBackColor = Color.LightGray,
               Docking = Docking.Right,
               BorderColor = Color.LightGray,
               BorderWidth = 1,
               BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid,
            };

         var item = new LegendItem();

         var column = new LegendCell
            {
               CellType = LegendCellType.Text,
               BackColor = Color.White,
               ForeColor = Color.Black,
               Text = "54 Data Values ",
               Alignment = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight
            };
         var item2 = new LegendItem();
         var column2 = new LegendCell
            {
               CellType = LegendCellType.Text,
               BackColor = Color.White,
               ForeColor = Color.Black,
               Text = "Maximum \t 14",
               Alignment = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight
            };
         var box = new Legend
            {
               Title = "Subgroup Stats",
               TitleAlignment = StringAlignment.Near,
               TitleBackColor = Color.LightGray,
               BorderColor = Color.LightGray,
               BorderWidth = 1,
               BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid
            };
         var boxRowOne = new LegendItem();
         var boxRowCell = new LegendCell
            {
               CellType = LegendCellType.Text,
               BackColor = Color.White,
               ForeColor = Color.Black,
               Text = "n=6",
               Alignment = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight
            };
         var boxRowTwo = new LegendItem();
         var boxRowTwoCell = new LegendCell
            {
               CellType = LegendCellType.Text,
               BackColor = Color.White,
               ForeColor = Color.Black,
               Text = "Estimated Sigma",
               Alignment = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft
            };
         var boxRowTwoCellTwo = new LegendCell
            {
                  CellType = LegendCellType.Text,
               BackColor = Color.White,
               ForeColor = Color.Black,
               Text = "1.82",
               Alignment = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft

            };

         item.Cells.Add( column );
         item2.Cells.Add( column2 );
         boxRowOne.Cells.Add(boxRowCell);
         boxRowTwo.Cells.Add(boxRowTwoCell);
         boxRowTwo.Cells.Add(boxRowTwoCellTwo);
         box.CustomItems.Add(boxRowOne);
         box.CustomItems.Add(boxRowTwo);
         legend.CustomItems.Add( item );
         legend.CustomItems.Add( item2 );
         chart.Legends.Add( legend );
         chart.Legends.Add( box );
         chart.Series[ 0 ].IsVisibleInLegend = false;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
chart.Legends[component].LegendStyle = LegendStyle.Column;

chart.Legends[component].Docking = Docking.Right;
```

Comment: Please supply explanation with your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `Position` explicitly, referring to the `Position` of the 1st `Legend`:

```
Legend L1 = chart10.Legends[0];
Legend L2 = new Legend("Legend Two");
L2.CustomItems.Add(new LegendItem("Legens Item 2.1", Color.Fuchsia, ""));

L2.Position = new ElementPosition(L1.Position.X, L1.Position.Bottom + 1, 
                                  L1.Position.Width, L1.Position.Height);
```

Note that all parts of an `ElementPosition` are given in **percentage** of the Element's container! So I added a `1%` gap..

Setting a suitable `Height` is somewhat tricky ;-)